# What's the difference between double exclamation operator and Boolean() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I know that `!!variable` will convert variable into a boolean value and the function `Boolean()`, according to the ecma262 spec, will also perform a type conversion by calling `ToBoolean(value)`.

My question is: what's the difference? Is `!!` better in performance than Boolean() ?

Comment: There is no `ToBoolean(var)`, just `Boolean(var)`

Comment: @sachleen I think he is referring to parts of the ecma spec.

Comment: My total guess is: absolutely no difference, and performance difference is negligible. But someone's gonna come around with some data soon enough.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are the same, as the `!` operator will call `ToBoolean()` internally on its operand, and then flip that returned value, while `Boolean()` will call `ToBoolean()` internally on its argument.